# Using python_requires to require Python 2.7 or 3.2+

Tags: python, python-2.7, setuptools, setup.py, pypi

How do I use `python_requires` classifier in setup.py to require Python 2.7.* or 3.2+?

I have tried many configurations, including this one: `~=2.7,==3,!=3.0,!=3.1,<4` but none have worked

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This argument for `setuptools` uses the [PEP440 version specifiers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#version-specifiers) spec, so you can ask for:

```
python_requires='>=2.7,!=3.0.*,!=3.1.*'
```

The commas `,` are equivalent to logical **and** operator.

Note that the metadata generated is [only respected by `pip>=9.0.0`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#v9-0-0) (Nov 2016).

Comment: See also the relevant [setuptools doc](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html?highlight=python_requires#new-and-changed-setup-keywords) and [PEP 345](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0345/).

Comment: See also: https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#python-requires

Comment: Sadly, following the links shows that the "," is treated as `and`, so something like "`==2.7, >=3.9`" will never work.